# How to make these two type definitions exactly the same?

Tags: flowtype

I'm wondering if there is another way to write a maybe type.

```
type Error = ?{name: string, message:string}
```

```
type Error = {name: string, message:string} | null
```

The above isn't the same since the `undefined` case isn't allowed in the second definition, but it is in the first. ([source](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAogTnA9nKBeKB+A3gOwIYC2EAXFAM7BwCWOA5gDRRFll60kXV0C+AUKJFgJkAJjRRchEuUo0GTCCzYdZPKAB8oOAK4AbXb166IwKADNEiYvCQp02nABMIZmhEdGT5yyOvC4YvZOLm6OQA))

However, the below doesn't work.

```
type Error = {name: string, message:string} | null | undefined
```

Is there another way to represent a maybe type without using the `?` prefix?

Comment: What do you mean by "flow"?  (The tag you used *explicitly* says it shouldn't be used.)

Comment: Thanks, I've replaced the tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Flow the type of `undefined` is `void`, so:

```
type Error = {name: string, message:string} | null | void
```

[Docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/primitives/#toc-null-and-void)

Answer (score 0):

This works!

```
type Error2 = {name: string, message:string} | null | typeof undefined
```